# Select first occurrence of list item in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list like this example:

abc, efg, rty

and a table with following data:

```
1 abcd
2 efgh
3 abcd
4 rtyu
5 efgh
```

now I want to find the first-row which start with list item in the table. my expected result is:

```
1 abcd
2 efgh
4 rtyu
```

Comment: "first-row" - First in what order? In a relational database, tables are unordered by nature - so there is no first row unless you can specify a column to sort by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a complete script to do the job

```
Declare @v_List Table
(
    Text nvarchar(100)
)

Declare @v_Data Table
(
    Number int,
    Text nvarchar(100)
)

Insert Into @v_List values(N'abc')
Insert Into @v_List values(N'efg')
Insert Into @v_List values(N'rty')

Insert Into @v_Data values(1, N'abcd')
Insert Into @v_Data values(2, N'efgh')
Insert Into @v_Data values(3, N'abcd')
Insert Into @v_Data values(4, N'rtyu')
Insert Into @v_Data values(5, N'efgh')

;with CTE as
(
    Select      D.Number,
                D.Text,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY L.Text Order By D.Number) as Row_No
    From        @v_Data D
    Join        @v_List L
        On      D.Text like L.Text + '%'
)
Select  CTE.Number,
        CTE.Text
From    CTE
Where   CTE.Row_No = 1
```

Comment: Finally, one answer that got it right! Please note, however, that this can be simplified by using `top 1 with ties` and `order by row_number...` as demonstrated in [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57668977/3094533)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from TableName
where Id in
(
    select min(Id) from
    (
        select Id, 
        case 
        when Val like 'abc%' then 1
        when Val like 'efg%' then 2
        when Val like 'rty%' then 3
        else 0 end temp
        from TableName
    )t where temp > 0
    group by temp
)
```

Comment: A cumbersome solution, but unlike most of the other 7 answers, that will get the desired results.

Comment: this is hardcoded solution but my list must be  create by another select

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowed `ROW_NUMBER` to generate a sequential number by each different value, then just display the first one only.

```
;WITH RowNumbersByValue AS
(
    SELECT
        T.ID,
        T.Value,
        RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.Value ORDER BY T.ID)
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
)
SELECT
    R.ID,
    R.Value
FROM
    RowNumbersByValue AS R
WHERE
    R.Value IN ('abcd', 'efgh', 'rtyu') AND
    R.RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server I prefer this version, which does not require a subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ID, Value
FROM yourTable
WHERE Value LIKE 'abc%' OR Value LIKE 'efg%' OR Value LIKE 'rty%'
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY ID);
```

Comment: what if values in the table was unique? I mean, instead of `abcd` in both ids 1 and 3, it was `abcd` in 1 and `abce` in 3? your solution would get both records in this case...

Comment: Do you see anything in the OP which supports your conjecture?

Comment: Well, Tim, we both have been here long enough to know that most of the times, the OP doesn't think of all the edge cases before posting a question. I'm just pointing out a potential pitfall in your answer. Also, it's highly unlikely that there's a constraint on the source table that prevents such cases.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this, there are so many ways to achieve this, use whichever suits you better.

using `subquery`

```
select id, col from 
        (select Row_number() over (partition by col order by id) as slno, id, col from yourtable) 
    as tb where tb.slno=1
```

using `cte`

```
; with cte as (
select row_number() over (partition by col order by id) as Slno, id, col from table)
select id, col from cte where slno=1
```

using `min`

```
select Min(id) , col from table group by col
```

### Note:-

In the end of any above mentioned query you may apply your where clause to filter your records as needed.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: how ..?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: hope now it is fine, Although I think we are here to give some help not writing exact query as people needed. It was just the idea of approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM (VALUES 
(1 ,'abcd'),
(2 ,'efgh'),
(3 ,'abcd'),
(4 ,'rtyu'),
(5 ,'efgh'))a([id], [name])
```

You can use min and group by function

```
SELECT MIN(id), name FROM #temp GROUP BY name
```